# R + Adding n number of weeks to YYYYWW format

Tags: r, date

I am trying to add 52 weeks to a date variable which is in YYYYWW format. my initial date is 201616 (year 2016 and week 16) and i am trying to add 52 weeks to this date and the expected output is 201715.

I tried couple of things but no luck, here is what i tried so far

```
date <- as.Date(as.character(201616), "%Y%W")
seq(date, by = "1 week", length.out = 52)
```

I would greatly appreciate your input. Many Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure that `as.Date` can take `%Y%W` and generate a unique value. It appears to be populating `date` with the current month and day. If instead we specify a date in the 16th week:

```
date <- as.Date("2016-04-23")
```

and format that in your style

```
format(date, "%Y%W")
[1] "201616"
```

we can generate a sequence of 52 values from this

```
newdate_seq <- seq(date, by = "1 week", length.out = 52)
```

and change those to your format too

```
format(newdate_seq, "%Y%W")
 [1] "201616" "201617" "201618" "201619" "201620" "201621" "201622" "201623" "201624" "201625" "201626" "201627"
[13] "201628" "201629" "201630" "201631" "201632" "201633" "201634" "201635" "201636" "201637" "201638" "201639"
[25] "201640" "201641" "201642" "201643" "201644" "201645" "201646" "201647" "201648" "201649" "201650" "201651"
[37] "201652" "201701" "201702" "201703" "201704" "201705" "201706" "201707" "201708" "201709" "201710" "201711"
[49] "201712" "201713" "201714" "201715"
```

which ends where you expect.

FYI, for next time, try highlighting what caused you to think there was "no luck" -- what errors did you produce, what results did you produce and how did they differ from what you expect to produce? Simply printing the `date` variable showed me that it wasn't doing what you expected.

Answer (score 6):

The problem is that there are 7 days in week #16 2016. You need to specify a day to convert it to a date that can be used to add days. In the code below `%u` indicates first day of the week. You can then add 52 weeks to this number.

```
date1 <- as.Date("201616 1", format = "%Y%U %u")
format(date1+(52*7), "%Y%U")
[1] "201716"
```

Comment: It might be worth pointing out that OP is using `%W` (week starting Monday, UK convention) while this answer has `%U` (week starting Sunday, US convention).